# Relacionamento entre duas entity

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony-2

É o seguinte, eu tenho uma entity Maquina e outra entity Previstas, e estão as duas no mesmo bundle.
O que eu pretendia era que na máquina 3, que já foi criada, de 100 mil em 100 mil fosse mudado o óleo da corrente de distribuição.

O código do Maquina.php

```
<?php

namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use RoqSys\Control\ControlBundle\Entity\Posto as Posto;

/**
 * Maquina
 *
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\MaquinaRepository")
 * 
 */
class Maquina 
{
    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", nullable=true, name="ciclo")
     */
    private $ciclo;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true, name="ultima")
     */
    private $ultima;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ControlBundle\Entity\Posto", inversedBy="maquina")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="posto_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     */
    private $posto;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Intervencao", mappedBy="maquina")
     */
    private $intervencao;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Prevista", mappedBy="maquina")
     */
    private $prevista;

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set ciclo
     *
     * @param integer $ciclo
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setCiclo($ciclo)
    {
        $this->ciclo = $ciclo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ciclo
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCiclo()
    {
        return $this->ciclo;
    }

    /**
     * Set ultima
     *
     * @param \DateTime $ultima
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setUltima($ultima)
    {
        $this->ultima = $ultima;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ultima
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUltima()
    {
        return $this->ultima;
    }

    /**
     * Set posto
     *
     * @param Posto $posto
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setPosto($posto)
    {
        $this->posto = $posto;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get posto
     *
     * @return Posto
     */
    public function getPosto()
    {
        return $this->posto;
    }

    public function __toString() {
    return "TESTE";
    }
}
```

O código da MaquinaController

```
<?php

namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina;
use RoqSys\Control\ControlBundle\Entity\Posto;
use RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Form\MaquinaType;

/**
 * Maquina controller.
 *
 * @Route("/manutencao/maquina")
 */
class MaquinaController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Lists all Maquina entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="manutencao_maquina")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }

     /**
     * Creates a new Intervencao entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/create", name="manutencao_maquina_create")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template("RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction($id)
    {          
        $maquina = new Maquina();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $posto = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlControlBundle:Posto')->find($id);
        $maquina->setPosto($posto);

        $em->persist($maquina);
        $em->persist($posto);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('manutencao_maquina_show', array('id' => $maquina->getId())));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Maquina entity.
     *
     * @param Maquina $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Maquina $entity) {
        $form = $this->createForm(new MaquinaType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('manutencao_maquina_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Maquina entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="manutencao_maquina_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = new Maquina();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $postos = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlControlBundle:Posto')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'postos' => $postos,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Maquina entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="manutencao_maquina_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Maquina entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Maquina entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="manutencao_maquina_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Maquina entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to edit a Maquina entity.
     *
     * @param Maquina $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createEditForm(Maquina $entity) {
        $form = $this->createForm(new MaquinaType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('manutencao_maquina_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Edits an existing Maquina entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="manutencao_maquina_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Maquina entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('manutencao_maquina_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a Maquina entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="manutencao_maquina_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id) {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Maquina entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('manutencao_maquina'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Maquina entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id) {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
                        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('manutencao_maquina_delete', array('id' => $id)))
                        ->setMethod('DELETE')
                        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
                        ->getForm()
        ;
    }

}
```

O código da Prevista.php

```
<?php

namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Prevista
 *
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\PrevistaRepository")
 */
class Prevista
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true, name="contagem")
     */
    private $contagem;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true, name="duracao")
     */
    private $duracao;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="titulo")
     */
    private $titulo;

    /**
     * @var string 
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="ficha")
     */
    private $ficha;

    /**
     * @var string 
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="descricao")
     */
    private $descricao;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true, name="ultima")
     */
    private $ultima;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina", inversedBy="prevista")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="maquina_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $maquina;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set contagem
     *
     * @param integer $contagem
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setContagem($contagem)
    {
        $this->contagem = $contagem;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contagem
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getContagem()
    {
        return $this->contagem;
    }

    /**
     * Set duracao
     *
     * @param integer $duracao
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setDuracao($duracao)
    {
        $this->duracao = $duracao;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get duracao
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDuracao()
    {
        return $this->duracao;
    }

    /**
     * Set titulo
     *
     * @param string $titulo
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setTitulo($titulo)
    {
        $this->titulo = $titulo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titulo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitulo()
    {
        return $this->titulo;
    }

    /**
     * Set ficha
     *
     * @param string $ficha
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setFicha($ficha)
    {
        $this->ficha = $ficha;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ficha
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFicha()
    {
        return $this->ficha;
    }

    /**
     * Set descricao
     *
     * @param string $descricao
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setDescricao($descricao)
    {
        $this->descricao = $descricao;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descricao
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescricao()
    {
        return $this->descricao;
    }

    /**
     * Set ultima
     *
     * @param \DateTime $ultima
     * @return Prevista
     */
    public function setUltima($ultima)
    {
        $this->ultima = $ultima;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ultima
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUltima()
    {
        return $this->ultima;
    }

    /**
     * Set maquina
     *
     * @param Maquina $maquina
     * @return Maquina
     */
    public function setMaquina($maquina)
    {
        $this->maquina = $maquina;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get maquina
     *
     * @return \Maquina
     */
    public function getMaquina()
    {
        return $this->maquina;
    }
}
```

O código da PrevistaController

```
<?php

namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Prevista;
use RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Form\PrevistaType;

/**
 * Prevista controller.
 *
 * @Route("/manutencao/prevista")
 */
class PrevistaController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Prevista entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="manutencao_prevista")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new Prevista entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="manutencao_prevista_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Prevista();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('manutencao_prevista_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Prevista entity.
     *
     * @param Prevista $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Prevista $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PrevistaType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('manutencao_prevista_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Prevista entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="manutencao_prevista_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = new Prevista();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        $entities = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'entities' => $entities,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Prevista entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="manutencao_prevista_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Prevista entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Prevista entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="manutencao_prevista_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Prevista entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Prevista entity.
    *
    * @param Prevista $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Prevista $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PrevistaType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('manutencao_prevista_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * Edits an existing Prevista entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="manutencao_prevista_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Prevista entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('manutencao_prevista_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a Prevista entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="manutencao_prevista_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Prevista entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('manutencao_prevista'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Prevista entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('manutencao_prevista_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

O código Previta.new

```
{# src/RoqSys/Control/ManutencaoBundle/Resources/views/Default/Prevista/new.html.twig #}
{% extends 'RoqSysBaseBundle:Default:base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block integer_widget %}
    <div class="col-md-6 integer_widget">
        {% set type = type|default('number') %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content -%}
    <h1>Nova Previsão</h1>
    <br>
    <ul class="record_actions">
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('manutencao_prevista') }}">
                Voltar para a lista
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    <div id="roqsys_control_manutencaobundle_prevista">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br>
                {{ form_label(form.contagem,'Contagem',{ 'label_attr': {'class':' col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-right'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.contagem) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.contagem) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <br>
                {{ form_label(form.duracao,{ 'label_attr': {'class':' col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-right'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.duracao) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.duracao) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <br>
                {{ form_label(form.titulo,'Título',{ 'label_attr': {'class':' col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-right'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.titulo) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.titulo) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <br>
                {{ form_label(form.ficha,'Ficha',{ 'label_attr': {'class':' col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-right'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.ficha) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.ficha) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <br>
                {{ form_label(form.descricao,'Descrição',{ 'label_attr': {'class':' col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-right'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.descricao) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.descricao) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <br>
                {{ form_label(form.ultima,'Ultima',{ 'label_attr': {'class':' col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-right'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.ultima) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.ultima) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label for="InputMaquina">Máquina</label
            <select>
                {% for maquina in entities %}
                    <option>
                        {{maquina.id}}

                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }} 
{% endblock %}
```

Pronto já tem todos os códigos, eu já dei voltas e voltas e ainda não consegui saber onde está o problema, e alguém saber como posso resolver ou o que se passa por favor ajudem-me.

Comment: tem muito código nessa pergunta!

Comment: mas tem de ser para verem se me consegues ajudar a descobrir qual o erro, o que está mal e o que alterar.

Comment: O que seria "máquina 3"? Seria a máquina de id 3? E de 100 mil em 100 mil, o quê? Ciclos da máquina? Contagens da prevista?

Comment: Sim é maquina com o id 3. Os 100 mil e em 100 mil é contagem.